# Force the browser to update translations files after deployment

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

We have an app built on Angular/Ionic. For the translations, we use `ngx-translate/core` package. Everything is deployed on Firebase hosting.

When we do a new build and deployment, Angular automatically generates a hash for `js` file names, and if it's changed, the browser understands that it needs to pull the latest version.

How we can do the same behavior for the `.json` file with translations?
The issue is that users do not receive the latest version of the translations after deployment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts` change your Module declaration to:

```js
TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (http: HttpClient) =>
              new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', `.json?v=${new Date().getTime()}`),
            deps: [HttpClient],
          },
        }),
```

That way each request sends a different request with a not needed queryParam, which will refetch the newest translation files.

Comment: If it works for you would be great if you could accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, sure. I accepted the answer and it seems to work when you develop locally. 

However, when I build it to deploy to the firebase hosting, it still adds it without a timestamp in the name.

So If I run serve locally, I see let's say `en.json?v=1670522904137`. However, if I deploy and open the site, I see just `en.json`.

Do you have an idea why?

Comment: It is probably related to building in production mode. I found this thread https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader/issues/25 with an answer that might work.

Extract the "hashDate" from the app.module into the enviroment folder and append "+ environment.hash" instead of the ${new Date().getTIme()}.


`export const environment ={
    hash: "${new Date().toISOString().replace(/\.|:|-/g,'')}"
}`